# SQL Server : how to use a variable in subquery within a linked server query

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, linked-server

I am trying to pull some information from a PostgresSQL linked server, but imposing some conditions using a table from the native SQL Server.

Ideally it should be something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM #transactions AS t
LEFT JOIN OPENQUERY(POSTGRES, '
                              SELECT *
                              FROM commission
                              WHERE timestamp > ''' SELECT start_time FROM #t '''
                              ')
ON t.id = c.id
```

Where `#transactions` and `#t` are temp tables on the SQL Server, while `POSTGRES` is the name for the linked server. The code cannot run successfully due to

> Incorrect syntax near '+'

EDIT: the table "commission" is a huge table so it would be better if I include the condition within the openquery instead of pulling everything first then do a filter.

Comment: Put the `Where` condition on the `JOIN ON t.id = c.id AND c.timestamp > t.start_time`

Comment: @WEI_DBA I appreciate the input. In my case the table in the openquery is huge so it would benefit me if I have the condition in the openquery instead of outside. Edited the question for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a variable value in an `OPENQUERY` call, you need to use an additional layer of complexity. Basically, you need to create dynamic SQL in a variable, then `EXEC` that dynamic SQL. Something like this, in your case:

```
DECLARE @SQL varchar(4000), -- whatever your query needs
    @StartTime datetime;

SELECT @StartTime = start_time FROM #t

SET @SQL = 'SELECT *
FROM #transactions AS t
LEFT JOIN OPENQUERY(POSTGRES, ''
                              SELECT *
                              FROM commission
                              WHERE timestamp > ''''' + @StartTime + '''''
                              '')
ON t.id = c.id'

EXEC(@SQL)
```

That's your best bet, because `OPENQUERY` does not accept dynamically built query strings.